# Unable to change name of feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I am in ArcView 9.3.  I have created a personal gdb and a Feature Class.  I was able to change the name of the gdb, but why CAN'T I change the name for the Feature Class (FC)?

Comment: Have you tried closing ArcMap and ArcCaralog, then renaming once you've reopened ArcCatalog? Could be a schema lock.

Comment: Is the feature class part of a network or topology?  You will not be able to rename it if it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a lock error?
That means one of a few things.
1. you have the map open with that data in it.
2. you have the map open with another fc from the same fds open.
3. you have services published from data in that fds and those services have been requested through a browser.
et al.

anyway in order you could try this.
1. shut down arcmap open (standalone) arccatlog and perform the rename.
2. start task manager and make sure ArcGISCacheMgr.exe is not running. 
   If it is kill it.
3. Go to the server and restart the soc/som processes. Then do your rename quickly before the data is requested again in a browser.

Comment: I can change the name ONLY if I start it with a  LETTER.

10.0 allows you to do it with a number.. just discovered that.

Comment: my client uses 10.0 and I have 9.3 and learning the differences between the two :)